# Responsive retina image

Tags: css, retina

I only want to serve up one image for all displays, so I have created an image 2000px wide which is double the display width, and set the width and height in the img tag with inline styling to 1000px wide and 242px high. I've added the bootstrap class called 'img-responsive' to the img tag which includes the following css code:

```
.img-responsive,
.thumbnail > img,
.thumbnail a > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

However now when the screen width reduces the image width scales but the height is fixed. How can I make both width and height scale with screen width and only use one double width image, without using retina.js, without using setsrc, and without using an svg file?

Comment: Use SVG images. All past and future problems solved. :)

Comment: Can you add a jsFiddle link? I'm not sure I understand the problem.

Comment: @WesFoster, using SVG images he would be having exactly the same issue as he does now. This is a css issue..

Comment: @Karolis But he's using inline styling to shrink a raster image so that it has retina features. Using a vector image in the first place would avoid the need to create a CSS workaround like this.

Comment: Look at the styles of parent container(s), and see if they have `overflow: hidden` set. Your image probably scales fine, but a part of it becomes hidden because of container styles.

Comment: @WesFoster the css is used to set image display size relative to parent container size. This has actually nothing to do with retina. He would have the same issue with 1x size image, 2x size image, 10x size image and SVG image as well. Also, from the given code I don't see it being inline. It looks very much like external css, considering it targets 5 selectors at once.

Comment: @Karolis The op said he "set the width and height in the img tag with inline styling" -- he just didn't include the code.

Comment: @WesFoster I was trying to point out that using SVG image would not make any difference in this situation. Wether the styles are set inline or from a css file, doesn't really matter.. The box model is the same for any image type.

Comment: @WesFoster either you've not read my question or you've totally ignored it. In anticipation of your kind of comment I clearly stated that I did not want to use SVG for reasons I'm not going to explain here. Will you please move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding important tag to height: auto. I think you have some other css affecting your style.

```
.img-responsive,
.thumbnail > img,
.thumbnail a > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Wow you're a star, it worked! The responsiveness worked fine until I added the inline width and height using CKEditor to scale down an image from 2000px to 1000px, so presumably the inline height was over riding the height auto, until I added !important as you suggested. Thank you.